# I'm having some problems trying to switch the __NSCFArray method

Tags: objective-c

I use the following method to swap __NSCFArray

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFArray");
Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, @selector(objectAtIndex:));
Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, @selector(f_objectAtIndex:));
method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2);
```

Error Message:

[image]

I compiled without error after changing __NSCFArray to __NSArrayI. But still want to ask what reason is next

```
+(void)initialize{
[super initialize];
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFArray");
Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, @selector(objectAtIndex:));
Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, @selector(f_objectAtIndex:));
method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2);
```

}

You can try running this code in the NSArray category

Comment: You should post code & errors as text, not screenshots. And why do you need to swap the methods? that's quite a rare implementation.

Comment: I tried to block crashes caused by data out of bounds. None of NSArray's other classes crash except __NSCFArray

Comment: Have you tried an exception breakpoint? Can't you fix the cause of the issue or use a Try-Catch-Finally Block? If you can't then post a [mre] please.

Comment: I've added the offending code snippet to the article

Comment: Interesting. Is it crashing even without you creating arrays explicitly? What are you trying to achieve here?